# Sql Bulk Copy Truncating Decimal

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, datatable

When I insert decimal values into Sql Server 2005 from a C# DataTable using bulk copy the values get truncated instead of rounded.

- The data type in the DataTable is Decimal.
- The data type in the database is Decimal(19,3)
- The value in the DataTable is 1.0005
- The value insert in the database is 1.000 (I expected 1.001)

The code I'm using is pretty simple:

```
var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, null) { DestinationTableName = tableName};
bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Can you round the values in the DataTable before calling WriteToServer?

Comment: Are you sure it is not rounding, if it is using ["To Even" or "Bankers Rounding"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) (This is what .NET uses by default). This makes it so `1.0005` would round to `1.000` however `1.0015` would round to `1.002`, when it needs to make a decision it rounds to the nearest even number to break a tie. I don't know if SQL does this our not, but you should check.

Comment: It truncating 1.0009 to 1.000 so it’s don’t think it’s a Bankers Rounding problem. When I add row using an update statement it rounds correctly. Michael I have hundreds of columns that are being truncated so rounding before would be a last resort. Also in the longer term we might want to increase the precision in the database. If I truncate in code I’d need to update the database and application.

Comment: Could precision may be the problem here? I mean `Decimal(19,3)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the reference source, [`SqlBulkCopy`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/fx/src/data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlBulkCopy.cs,ba5d0d80c109eaa7) always truncates decimal values instead of rounding, which unfortunately differs from the behavior of the BULK INSERT statement.

The private [`ConvertValue`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/fx/src/data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlBulkCopy.cs,721836dc8101d274) method calls [`TdsParser.AdjustSqlDecimalScale`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/fx/src/data/System/Data/SqlClient/TdsParser.cs,47150fd320d829ad) if the scale of the source value differs from the scale of the destination column:

```
switch(type.NullableType) {
    case TdsEnums.SQLNUMERICN:
    case TdsEnums.SQLDECIMALN:
        // ...

        if (sqlValue.Scale != metadata.scale) {                            
            sqlValue = TdsParser.AdjustSqlDecimalScale(sqlValue, metadata.scale);  
        }
```

`AdjustSqlDecimalScale` in turn calls [`SqlDecimal.AdjustScale`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.data.sqltypes.sqldecimal.adjustscale(v=vs.100).aspx), passing `false` for `fRound`:

```
static internal SqlDecimal AdjustSqlDecimalScale(SqlDecimal d, int newScale) {
    if (d.Scale != newScale) {
        return SqlDecimal.AdjustScale(d, newScale - d.Scale, false /* Don't round, truncate.  MDAC 69229 */);
    }

    return d;
}
```

There's apparently no way to override this behavior and pass `true` to `AdjustScale`, so if you want to use `SqlBulkCopy`, you will need to round the values in the `DataTable` yourself before calling `WriteToServer`.

Alternatively, you could write the data to a file and execute BULK INSERT directly, forgoing `SqlBulkCopy`.

Comment: Where is that reference source?

Comment: @ScumSprocket: I've corrected the hyperlinks in my answer.