# EF BulkInsert doesn't honour SQLProviderServices setup

Tags: c#, entity-framework, bulkinsert

Possible XY problem: I need my code not to truncate decimals when writing to the Database.
See here: https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/26392489/entity-framework-code-first-truncating-my-decimals

I have successfully configured my EF dbContext so that it sends the full decimal to SQL Server, to be rounded appropriately.

i.e. I have set `SqlProviderServices.TruncateDecimalsToScale = false;`

Running a test with a normal EF "write this object to its Dataset and `.Savechanges()`" works fine.

But when I do the same conceptual operation with the BulkInsert library ([link](https://github.com/ghost1face/EntityFramework.BulkInsert)) it doesn't honour the setting.

Is there a sane way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is likely a result of the underlying .NET Framework class being poorly implemented.

As per here: [Sql Bulk Copy Truncating Decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23566373/sql-bulk-copy-truncating-decimal) the underlying `SqlBulkCopy` class does not allow the option of rounding decimals, even though it could in principle do so.

So any BulkInsert library that uses SqlBulkCopy will suffer from this problem.

---

My solution was to replace the auto-property with an backing field and a rounding setter.
This also has the advantage of allowing control over the rounding strategy, if you care about whether it uses `.ToEven()` or `.AwayFromZero()`. Note that C# does the former, by default, but SQL does the latter. :(